# Part of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Installed on C Drive

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I wanted to install VS 2017 Enterprise completely onto my D drive. I installed every package available in the 2017 installer. However, despite me specifically setting the IDE and Shared Library folders to the D drive, my storage on my C Drive went down. What could have installed on my C drive, and can I move them to the D Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of 3rd party components that are installed with Visual Studio Enterprise and some of these install into your user profile, some into ProgramData etc. Then there are a number that may be installed elsewhere, but the Visual Studio installer has no way to provide a better location to that installer when running a silent install.

After installation you can't easily move stuff to other drives.

You only alternative is to install most 3rd party components yourself, not through the Visual Studio Installer. The cheaper solution is probably to buy a larger drive and mirror the data over to the new drive.